# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' in Vite build

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm encountering an error while building my Vite project. The error message I'm receiving is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (at bundle.js:265:26574)." I'm unsure about what is causing this error and how to resolve it.